# Kafka wait for minimal number of consumers (clients) in KStream

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a distributed KStream application, where processing is memory intensive. When there is some problem, for example all nodes are restarted / crash at the same time, first node to start usually gets all the partitions and it takes some time before partitions get assigned to another node(s).

Is there any way to specify minimal number of consumers which need to be alive before KStream (Kafka) starts processing of data? Even if there would be some lag before they get alive? Therefore my load would be more evenly distributed from the start and I will not overload one node?

Answer (score 1):

There is broker configuration that seems to do what you are looking for, hope it helps

group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms
The amount of time the group coordinator will wait for more consumers to join a new group before performing the first rebalance. A longer delay means potentially fewer rebalances, but increases the time until processing begins.

Type:   int
Default:    3000 (3 seconds)
Valid Values:
Importance: medium
Update Mode:    read-only